# Finding a window and setting focus on it

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

1.I want to find a window and set focus on it , but window is not taking the focus.

2.If i use HWND_TOP then it does not make the window active and if i use HWND_TOPMOST then  it make window always on top.

Can anyone help me ??

```
HWND hwndAppDlg = ::FindWindowEx(hwndDesktop,NULL,lpszClass,lpszWindow);

    if(hwndAppDlg && IsWindow(hwndAppDlg))
    {
        CRect rcAppDlg;
        if( 0 == ::GetWindowRect(hwndAppDlg,rcAppDlg))
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"\n GetWindowRect failed...");           
            return FALSE;
        }
        if(0 == ::SetWindowPos(hwndAppDlg,HWND_TOPMOST,rcAppDlg.left,rcAppDlg.top,rcAppDlg.Width(),rcAppDlg.Height(),SWP_SHOWWINDOW))
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"\n SetWindowPos failed...");            
            return FALSE;
        }
        if(0 == ::PostMessage(hwndAppDlg,WM_SETFOCUS,0,0))
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"\n WM_SETFOCUS failed");        
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're sending WM_SETFOCUS, but that does not set the focus. That message is sent to a control if it gained or lost the focus, but when that message is sent/received, the focus change has already happened.

To actually set the focus (you don't need to send the WM_SETFOCUS message), use [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646312%28VS.85%29.aspx)() if you know which control in the dialog should get the focus, or [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28VS.85%29.aspx)() to set the focus to the dialog itself and let the dialog determine which subcontrol actually will get the focus.
Both of these APIs will send WM_SETFOCUS automatically.

Answer (score 2):

How about [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28VS.85%29.aspx)( hwndAppDlg, SW_SHOW );

Comment: it does not even activate the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I have used  `::SetForegroundWindow(hwndAppDlg)`  to activate and set focus on the dialog and it works cool.